# ideas for removing background fringes using opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

basically i wrote a code that had two images. a reference img and a background img. So far i have successfully found the matching image by using feature recognition. Then i rotated it and resized it to look identical as the reference image. The only problem left is the fact that the image as some of the background image on the fringes of the object. This image has been appropriately cropped so i just need to work with the image below. The most obvious answer that first came to me was perhaps use a edge detection algorithm (canny) and use that to give me a clue on where the background may lie. However since the images itself could technically be anything i feel like there would be lots of noise and various unusual errors so if possible i would rather not want to take that path. I also saw the backgroundsubtraction MOG but it seemed like that works for videos and not for single stilled image. In case i was wrong i tried the following code but had 0 effect:

```
  BackgroundSubtractorMOG  bs_mog(3, 4, 0.8);
  Mat foreground_mog;
  bs_mog (cropped_img,  foreground_mog, -1.0);
```

Perhaps i am doing it wrong. So my thought is other than edge detection and if backgroundsubtractorMOG is only for moving images are there any other ideas or options i can look into to remove the fringe background image (i want to turn it all into just white)

[image]

thank you in advance for your ideas and comments

EDIT:

well i unerstand the logic already posted by others but i am unsure what the best way to make a mask for this bottom image would be. It is important to note that the image can technically be anything. Not necessary round in shape. Also due to changes in the algorithm the shape must be resized after the object is separated from the background. This means i can't use my reference image to just make a mask and use that mask on this image due to the difference in size.

Comment: Can you create a mask from your reference image and use that to retain just the region of interest using a logical AND with the background image?

Answer (score 0):

Segmentation could work. Try `cvgrabCut()` with a [customized mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14111716/how-to-set-a-mask-image-for-grabcut-in-opencv).

- Set as *background* all pixels very close to borders. (red in image below)
- Set as *foreground* the center area of your image. (green in image below)
- Any intermediate pixels set them to *probably foreground*. (gray in image below)

[image]