# Improving Grabcut in OpenCV

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, image-segmentation

I just implemented the GrapCV-algorithm (OpenCV, C++, Visual Studio 12):

> grabCut( *image, mask, rect, bgdModel, fgdModel, 1, GC_INIT_WITH_MASK
>   );

I used it to segment to following picture:

[image]

My result is this:

[image]

My question is: How i am able now to improve the algorithm, so that only the both players can be seen? My first idea was a change concerning the colors depth, but i don't know how to send it to "grabCut". Or are there other ways?

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14111716/how-to-set-a-mask-image-for-grabcut-in-opencv/14124334#14124334). Segment each person with its own rectangle and set border pixels as background.

Comment: Nice idea, thank you! The problem is, that my result should be very user-friendly: The user should mark by just one rectangle to get his/her result.

Comment: Use an object detector inside that user defined area and then segment as told.

Comment: Unfortunaly, this method produces results even worse.

Comment: Classify pixels based on their blurriness to guide masked segmentation. Use entropy, or a filter2D. Share if you find anything good.

Answer (score 0):

In the folder *opencv2.4.6/samples/cpp*, there are a lot of files that demonstrate the use of some classical algorithms. There is a file called *grabcut.cpp* which tells you how to apply this algorithm to your application in detail. So what you need to do is just embed this file into your program.

If you have any other questions, just debug with the grabcut.cpp and you would see how it works in detail. And if you wanna implement it by yourself. you need to change the function with new parameter `GC_EVAL` or `GC_INIT_WITH_MASK`.

```
grabCut(image,    // input image
    mask,   // segmentation mask
    rect,// rectangle containing foreground
    bgModel,fgModel, // models
    2,        // number of iterations
    GC_INIT_WITH_RECT); // use rectangle
```