# How to improve Grabcut in the case when the bottom part of the image isn't a part of the background?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation

When I'm running Grabcut on an image,
I set the bounding box of grabcut to the edges of the image itself.

[image]

However, since the bottom of the image is a part of the foreground not background, it cuts out the lower part.

[image]

Is there any way of preventing this, such as setting the boundary box only to the top, left and right?

Comment: what interface/api you are using for GrabCut?

Comment: I'm using OpenCV Java

Answer (score 1):

GrabCut needs the boundary to define what is "outside" so it can compute a background color model. Depending on your API/interface you might be able to define "outside" only from the right-top and left parts of the image, leaving the bottom "inside".

Assuming you are using [`cv::grabCut`](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#ga909c1dda50efcbeaa3ce126be862b37f), you may define the initial `rect` to exceed the bottom part of the image, in that case the algorithm should not consider the lower part to be *"obvious background"*.

Comment: Great suggestion. Unfortunately however, it seems to consider large parts of a plain white background as foreground now also but atleast the bottom part isn't being cut off anymore and will play around with it to see if I can improve it.

Comment: @CheenuMadan how tight is your `rect`? if it contains a lot of "white" area to begin with, how do you expect the algorithm to know that "white" is not foreground?

Comment: Good point. Finding the contours of the image to see if I can draw a bounding box around it and then will use that. Does that approach sound good?

Comment: @CheenuMadan You might want to look into something like [edge boxes](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/220569/ZitnickDollarECCV14edgeBoxes.pdf).

Comment: Hi Shai, thanks for the comment. I went with the above method and the grabcut algorithm works pretty great considering most of my images have a white or whitish background. I'll look into edge boxes in case I need further improvements. Once again, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As the background in this image is quite clean, you may try some rules to segment the foreground in this case. For examples, why don't you remove the “relatively” white regions. The color of background can be heuristically extracted from the boundary region of images.

If there is cluttered background in your data set, you may try to detect a tighter bounding box for the human by using detectors, such as [DPM](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~rbg/latent/), or [R-CNN](https://github.com/rbgirshick/rcnn). They already provide some powerful models for human detection. Based on the detected box, I suppose the result of grabcut should be better.

Anyway, it should be helpful to provide some more examples for analysis.

Answer (score 0):

classic gab cut implemented in openCV has 6 Gaussian mixture models corresponding to 6 centroids in 3D color space - more than you need to model the image above. Thus your problem is in setting correct labels. You have to set not only bounding box or ROI but 3 regions with 3 labels - FG, BG, PROBABLY_BG (partition the image). The former two will contribute to the models of foreground and background on the basis of which the latter label will be the only region where the boundary is refined. In other words, you did not do correct initialization of grab cut with three labels. See this, for example [How to set a mask image for grabCut in OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14111716/how-to-set-a-mask-image-for-grabcut-in-opencv?lq=1)